# Run a script function after Paste

Tags: javascript

I'm designing a table for a parking lot can lead to control of time entering and leaving the car, and how much to pay.
A sheet has the name "Ingreso" and in cell C2 will insert manually the ticket number that is given to the client.
On that sheet is a button that when clicking run the function copyAndDelete which is the following script:

```
function copyAndDelete () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("Ingreso!C2:C2");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Prueba");
  // Determinar la ubicación de la primera fila vacía.
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear ();

}﻿

function onEdit(event)
{
  var RegistEnt = 'Registro'; //Es la hoja que estamos cambiando dinámicamente
  var lcol = 1; //# Columna izquierda que se está evaluando
  var tcol = 2; //# Columna donde estampamos la hora fecha actual.
  //

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //Activa la hoja de calculo en la que se esta trabajando el Script
  var sname = s.getName();

 if (sname == RegistEnt)
  {
    var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(); //Activa el rango donde se captura el texto
    var scol = r.getColumn(); 
    if (scol >= lcol && scol <= tcol)
    {
      s.getRange(r.getRow(), tcol).setValue(new Date()); //Dispara el registro en la columna donde va el resultado
    }
  }
}﻿
```

I have another sheet in the same Spreadsheet named "Registro" where will paste the ticket number in column 1, and in column 2 will generate the date and time it is inserted the ticket number. I put a script that when Column 1 is edited it puts the date and hour in Column 2. This is the script:

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var RegistEnt = 'Registro'; //Es la hoja que estamos cambiando dinámicamente
  var lcol = 1; //# Columna izquierda que se está evaluando
  var tcol = 2; //# Columna donde estampamos la hora fecha actual.
  //

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //Activa la hoja de calculo en la que se esta trabajando el Script
  var sname = s.getName();

 if (sname == RegistEnt)
  {
    var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(); //Activa el rango donde se captura el texto
    var scol = r.getColumn(); 
    if (scol >= lcol && scol <= tcol)
    {
      s.getRange(r.getRow(), tcol).setValue(new Date()); //Dispara el registro en la columna donde va el resultado
    }
  }
}﻿
```

The problem is that it have the onEdit function, so it doesn´t insert the date and time because I have to edit the cells in column 1 of sheet "Registro", but I want that it put the date and time after the function copyAndDelete paste the value in the sheet "Registro"

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `onpaste` event to trigger the script:

```
var el = document.getElementById('sourceCol');
el.addEventListener('paste', onEdit);
```

Read more about the `onpaste` event [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpaste.asp).